# Types of errors docker in Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

When I began to start docker it stuck and there are so many bad problem with it

System: Windows 8.1 64-bit

I replace virtualbox 5.0.6 to virtualbox 5.0.7 Still, there's an error

Error One:

When Docker Quickstart Terminal want to begin  Starting VM... is hanging

Error two

I test my installation with docker run hello-world I get the following:

> Post http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.20/containers/create: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..
>   * Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
>   * Is your docker daemon up and running?

Error three

Kinematic doesn't work 
It work until 99% BUT suddenly it doesn't work

> Machine IP could not be fetched. Please retry the setup. If this fails please file a ticket on our GitHub repo.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution I've found after googling for a while:

First check if your Virtualbox version is the latest or at least above 5, then

1. Run on CMD `docker-machine rm -f ##dockerContainerName##` (Generally: default)
2. Delete .docker folder from your user folder
3. Run `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox ##dockerContainerName##`
4. Profit!!!